# Evaluating an expression using a stack (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I need to make a stack that evaluates expression in the same way it would in racket. Here is an example of working output:

```
Please enter the racket expression to be evaluated: 
(+ 3 (* 2 20))
+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       20        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       2        |
|       20        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       40        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       3        |
|       40        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       43        |
==================

The result is: 43

Would you like to enter another expression (Y/N)?
```

In this instance my pop function is working fine and as intended. When I make the expression a little more complicated though the pop function stops working. I'm confused why though because it is utilizing the same code. Here is an example of output where the pop function isn't working:

```
Please enter the racket expression to be evaluated: 
(+ (*2 4) (+ 10 2))
+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       2        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       10        |
|       2        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       12        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       4        |
|       12        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       2        |
|       4        |
|       12        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       8        |
|       2        |
|       4        |
|       12        |
==================

+--TOP OF STACK--+
|       10        |
|       8        |
|       2        |
|       4        |
|       12        |
==================

The result is: 10

Would you like to enter another expression (Y/N)?
```

It works fine for the (+ 10 2) part of the expression and the 10 and 2 are popped as expected. Then the 4 and 2 are pushed as expected but when they are popped, they aren't getting popped off the stack and the correct number 8 is getting pushed so I know the pop function has been called. I stepped through and the stack looks fine until it gets to that point where for some reason pop gets called but it doesn't remove the old digits just returns their value.

Here is my pop function:

```
int pop(Node** top)
{
    int pop = (*top)->digit; //stores the value to be returned.
    *top = (*top)->prev; //"pops" the top element off the stack.

    return pop; //returns the digit as an integer
}
```

Here is the push function:

```
void push(Node** stackEnd, int digit)
{
    Node* ptr = *stackEnd;        // used to traverse the list

    // set up new node
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->digit = digit;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    // add node to linked list
    if (*stackEnd == NULL)
            *stackEnd = newNode;           // first node in list
    else
    {
            // find the end of the list
            while (ptr->next != NULL)
                    ptr = ptr->next;

            // update pointers
            ptr->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = ptr;
    }

    // assign new endPtr
    *stackEnd = newNode;
}
```

and here is the part in main I feel is relevant. The pop is called in the else statement at the bottom when an operator is found:

```
Node* startPtr = NULL;      //nodes for linked list that will be used for the expression
    Node* endPtr = NULL;
    Node* stackEnd = NULL;      //node for the stack
    char expression[SIZE];     //variable to hold the expression the user inputs
    char again = 'Y';          //to determine if the user wants to input another expression
    int total = 0;             //used to keep track of total when evaluating the expression.
    int digit;                 //variable to store the digit that will be pushed on the stack

    //these variables will be used in determining a digit > 9
    char multDigit[SIZE] = "";
    char digitSwap[SIZE] = "";
    int j = 0;
    int k;

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter the racket expression to be evaluated: \n");
        fgets(expression, SIZE, stdin);

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++)        //builds the linked list for the expression using a for loop
            insertNode(&startPtr, expression[i], &endPtr);

        while(endPtr != NULL)
        {
            if(isspace(endPtr->element))                         //if the last element in the list is a space or new line we move onto the prev node
                endPtr = endPtr->prev;
            else if(endPtr->element == '(' || endPtr->element == ')')    //if the last element is a paren we move to the prev node
                endPtr = endPtr->prev;
            else if(isdigit(endPtr->element) && !(isdigit(endPtr->prev->element))) //if it is a single digit (0-9)
            {   
                digit = endPtr->element - '0';
                endPtr = endPtr->prev;
                push(&stackEnd, digit); //pushes the digit onto the stack
                printStack(&stackEnd);       //when something is pushed onto the stack we want to display the new stack to the user.
            }
            else if(isdigit(endPtr->prev->element))     //if the digit is > 9
            {
                //puts together a char array of the digit >9                
                while(isdigit(endPtr->element))
                {
                    multDigit[j] = endPtr->element;
                    endPtr = endPtr->prev;
                    j++;
                }

                //reverse it so it is in the proper order
                k = 0;

                while(j > 0)
                {
                    digitSwap[k] = multDigit[j-1];  //we need to use another variable digitSwap to store the reversed char array
                    k++;
                    j--;
                }

                digit = atoi(digitSwap); //translates the char array into an int
                push(&stackEnd, digit); //pushes the digit onto the stack
                printStack(&stackEnd);  //when something is pushed onto the stack we want to display the new stack to the user.
            }
            else //the element must be an operator(+, -, /, etc)
            {
                char operator = endPtr->element;

                total = (evaluate((pop(&stackEnd)), operator, (pop(&stackEnd)))); //pop the stack twice to evaluate
                push(&stackEnd, total);    //push the total onto the stack
                printStack(&stackEnd);       //when something is pushed onto the stack we want to display the new stack to the user.
                endPtr = endPtr->prev;
            }
        }
```

Edit: in case it is confusing how my code is working. I am using a doubly linked list to traverse the expression which is a character array. I traverse it from the end to the front so for  example: (+ 3 2)

```
expression[0]  = '(' 
expression [1] = '+'
expression[2] = ' '
```

etc, etc....

I traverse it backwords using `endPtr` which starts at `')'` in this example and then I use `-> prev` to work my way backwords.

Comment: You got to provide [mcve]

Comment: Usually the operator follows the values in UPN and stack calculators.  2, 20, +. Because the stack only takes values, not operators, the values have to come first. With the first operator you need two values on your stack.

Comment: Anytime I post anything on stack overflow I get this same response. What do you want me to do? I provided the output that I'm getting. Explained what is happening, described the troubleshooting steps I have gone through. I don't know how to make the post more "minimal" without taking away from the "complete" portion of this rule.

Comment: @Holger it needs to be in the order that it is because my instructor wants me to use a stack to evaluate a racket expression like it is done in racket. The way I have it is how it is done in racket. The stack doesn't need to handle operators because when an operator is reached in the code it pops the stack twice (the values) and applies the operator. There is no part in the code where the operator gets pushed on the stack

Comment: @Sauromayne From the given code we will not able to figure out the problem. Problem can be some where else in the not provided code.

Comment: @kiran Biradar what is missing from the code that you would like to see? I can paste as much of it as needed. You want to see the push function as well? I tried to paste as minimal as possible because I know people don't want to waste their time looking through a bunch of code

Comment: @Sauromayne We need minimal complete code which produces the same behavior.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I edited the post to include more of main and I have included the push function as well. I assure that Node is set up correctly and I have stepped through and confirmed that insertNode() is functioning as intended and it doesn't play a role in my issue.

Comment: Why do you need `insertNode()` function when you have `push()` function already.

Answer (score -1):

This looks very complicated in your source.
Your stack only needs to be an int array with a top-index. And there is no need to split the expression in many nodes.
I have no compiler at hand, so this is only an **untested sample**.

I think you have to have a look at the correct order of pop() in the call to calculate()

```
int stack[64], stacktop=-1;

void push(int val) {
    stacktop++;
    stack[stacktop] = val;
}
int pop() {
    return (stacktop>=0) ? stack[stacktop--] : 0;
}

int evaluate(char *buf) {
    char *ptr, *mark, *pcpy, *pcpy2, buf2[256];

    for(ptr=buf; *ptr ; ptr++);    // goto end of buf
    for(ptr--; ptr>=buf; ptr--) {
        if(isspace(*ptr)) continue;
        if(*ptr=='(' || *ptr==')') continue;
        for(mark=ptr; ptr>=buf && isdigit(*ptr); ptr--); // test for digits
        if(ptr!=mark) {                                  // found at least 1 digit
            ptr++;
            for(pcpy2=buf2, pcpy=ptr; pcpy<=mark; pcpy++, *pcpy2++)
                *pcpy2=*pcpy;
            *pcpy2='\0';
            push(atoi(buf2));
            continue;
        }
        if(*ptr=='+' || *ptr=='-' || *ptr=='*' || *ptr=='/') {
            push(calculate(pop(), *ptr, pop()));
        }
    }
    return pop();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: I think, it does. If you reduce unnessessary compexity, you will get a programm that runs more stable

Comment: Using different datastructure to implement the same functionality may have overhead but it comes with its own benefits.

Comment: Hmm, adding every char of a string (including blanks) in a node chain has benefits? 
Anyway, thanks for downvoting